# WPF 3D algorithm question: what model does it use?

Tags: c#, wpf, algorithm, 3d

Please refer to Wiki definitions about 3d modeling, what modeling algorithm WPF 3d use? 
Polygon or NURBS?

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 1):

You can do both, although you will probably find polygons easier to work with.

Here's an overview of [geometry and shapes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751808.aspx) in WPF, and a [good WPF 3d tutorial](http://www.kindohm.com/technical/WPF3DTutorial.htm)

Answer (score 0):

WPF can display Polygons models.

you can convert nurbs model to polygon when exporting objects from a modeling software

but WPF CAN'T read Nurbs data and display the model.